# Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, command

I'm coding a Command (queue) in laravel 5.0 and when I run php artisan queue:listen it is all right and working but I get

> [ErrorException]
> Undefined index: HTTP_HOST

in queue return.

```
public function handle()
{
    $empresa_id = $this->empresa_id;
    $empresa = Empresas::find($empresa_id);
    
    if($empresa->used_storage_record > $empresa->limit_storage_record)
    {
        do{
            $registros = RepositorioRegistro::where('activo', 1)->whereHas('Documento', function ($query) use ($empresa_id){
                $query->where('empresa_id', $empresa_id);
            })->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

            if(!count($registros))
                break;

            $registros->activo = 0;
            $registros->save();

            $registros = RepositorioRegistro::where('activo', 1)->whereHas('Documento', function ($query) use ($empresa_id){
                $query->where('empresa_id', $empresa_id);
            })->get();
            $bytes = 0;
            foreach($registros as $registro)
            {
                if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists("/{$empresa_id}/registros/{$registro->url}"))
                {
                    $bytes += Storage::size("/{$empresa_id}/registros/{$registro->url}");
                }
            }
            $empresa->used_storage_record = $bytes;

            $empresa->save();
        }while($empresa->used_storage_record > $empresa->limit_storage_record);
    }

    return 'true';
}
```

Comment: can you show the line the error is referring to?

Comment: @lagbox This is a problem because queues does not specify the exact line, but I think that I'm not using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: did you look at the error log?

Comment: @lagbox had not thought of that, I just looked and I found a updated model event of EmpresasController that is using  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_HOST is set by browser therefore it works only on the browser.

It can not work when you use PHP CLI.

Comment: But when I'm using HTTP_HOST?

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. HTTP_HOST will never work from command prompt. php artisan is a command prompt utility.